# Communication between fragments in android

Tags: android

I am new to android I want to accept a string in a fragment which will pass that string to another fragment which has a webview in it. how to do it i am not getting anything.

Please Help

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bundle and setArgument:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

               YourNextFragment mm=new YourNextFragment ();
               Bundle b=new Bundle();
               b.putString("key", value);
               mm.setArguments(b);

            transaction.replace(R.id.yourContainer, mm);

            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

// you can use String yourString=getArguments().getString("key"); to access this string in your next fragment

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a common question... the most accepted answer is to go via the Activity that hosts your Fragments. One reason for this is that Fragments can be considered 'views' on your application state, and hence should be stateless. [Here](http://thecodeworld.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/communicating-between-fragments-in-android/) is an article about it.